# Remove colors from OPAM output

Tags: ocaml, opam

How do I remove colors from the output of OPAM install or OPAM switch create?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 on Windows 10.
I have already removed colors from the terminal settings and .bashrc.

For example:
ls --help gives an output without colors
whereas
opam --help gives a very colorful output

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `--color=never` (the other possible values being `always` and `auto`)

(This is the second option listed in the output from `opam --help`, btw)

Comment: I tried the following command:
 opam --color=never --help

and I still don't get the help without colors.

I did python3 --help and it is showing without colors too

Comment: I did not notice the second option in the help section mostly because I am color blind and the current color scheme isn't allowing me to see the entire content. :(

I have set my TERM env variable to xterm-mono. yet OPAM somehow isn't reacting to this like other commands are

Comment: The --color=never option does seem to work for other opam commands though

How do I add this to an alias so I  don't have to type it everytime?

Comment: `opam` seems to be using `man` to display its help page, which is turn uses a pager like `more`, `less` or `most`, so I'm not sure this is within its control. I don't get colorized output on either my macOS or Manjaro boxes, even with `--color=always`, so it seems to be something specific to your system configuration.

Comment: Aliases also depend on your system, specifically your shell. If using bash I believe you can just put `alias opam=opam --color=never` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`